# Is there any order to cover the image of the img tag for the background image?

Tags: html, css

It was inserted into the background image to the class li.

Inside li class img tag has.

The background image on the li class  tag, how do you occupy the top than that?

```
<style>
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 625px;
}
.ul-wrap {
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}
li.full-image.guest_bulr {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAQElEQVQoU2NkIAJ4e3sbMxJSB1K0devWs3gVwhSBDMOpEFkRToXoirAqxKYIQyEuRSgK8SmCKySkCKyQGEUghQBteCUf8jBb4wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 980px;
    height: 625px;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(21, 18, 18, 0.9);
    zoom: 1;
    background-size: cover;
}

.wrap img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

</style>

<div class="wrap">
    <ul class="ul-wrap">
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" alt="image" class="first-img">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please try to restate or reword your question. I'm not sure what problem you are having or what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.first-img` relative. 
See working example.

```css
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 625px;
}
.ul-wrap {
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.ul-wrap li {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAQElEQVQoU2NkIAJ4e3sbMxJSB1K0devWs3gVwhSBDMOpEFkRToXoirAqxKYIQyEuRSgK8SmCKySkCKyQGEUghQBteCUf8jBb4wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
  display: block; 
  position: relative;
  width: 980px;
  height: 625px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.wrap img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.first-img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <ul class="ul-wrap">
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" alt="image" class="first-img">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Edmar how did you know what the OP was asking?